# Why does Appium sign the .apk? Is there any benefit?

Tags: appium

I've been using Appium for automation in Android, I always was surprised for the resigning of the apk.

This signing only has caused problems to me, and I cannot see any advantage of this 'feature'.

When there were problems, I simply add the nosign configuration, and all worked correctly, and never see any side effect doing it.

So, is there any benefit of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my research and knowledge:

1. Appium **relies on instrumentation** for certain features (**requires 
   signing**) so you'll want to sign using your known key **to avoid the 
   tamper detection problems**.
2. It **should be possible to support not signing** when using only 
   uiautomator.
3. You can automate Android apk files using appium, **as long as you have the apk binary**.
4. **iOS requires a signed developer build**.
5. Point in the introduction page states that "You **shouldn't have to recompile your app** or modify it in any way **in order to automate it**." So that **means we do not need to re-sign the apk to automate** with appium.